# boto S3 & flask error - Authorization header is invalid -- one and only one ' ' (space) required

Tags: python, amazon-s3, flask, boto

I have some code that was working just fine yesterday - now I'm getting an error.

```
s3 = get_s3_connection()
b_temp = s3.get_bucket(current_app.config['AWS_S3_BUCKET_TEMP'])
b_assets = s3.get_bucket(current_app.config['AWS_S3_BUCKET_ASSETS'])
```

I get the following stack trace, which dumps the response:

```
ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
  <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
  <Message>Authorization header is invalid -- one and       only one ' ' (space required</Message>

<ArgumentValue>AWS &lt;flask.app.Flask objecat0x1043d2e90&gt;:AbKV0ZvU6B0XXXXXXXXXX=       
</ArgumentValue>
<ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName>
```

Getting b_temp works fine. The error happens on the second `get_bucket` - why is boto doing this?

Comment: It looks like you are passing in a Flask object to `get_bucket()` which boto is attempting to convert to a string and then send to Amazon. What does `current_app.config['AWS_S3_BUCKET_ASSETS']` contain?

Comment: I'm dumping to my logger - its dumping the config value properly

Comment: Also.. I stated the issue incorrectly above. its throwing the error on this line: `b_temp = s3.get_bucket(current_app.config['AWS_S3_BUCKET_TEMP'])`

Comment: What does `print type(current_app.config['AWS_S3_BUCKET_TEMP'])` print?